# Saving a PDF returned by service

Tags: javascript, angularjs, pdf

I'm using [FileSaver.js](https://github.com/eligrey/FileSaver.js) and [Blob.js](https://github.com/eligrey/Blob.js) into an Angular JS application to save a PDF returned by a REST service (which returns an array of bytes representing the file).

```
var headers = {headers: {"Authorization":"Bearer "+token, "Accept":"application/pdf"}};

  $http.get(URL, headers)
    .success(function (data) {
      var blob = new Blob([data], {type: 'application/pdf'});
      saveAs(blob, 'contract.pdf');
    });
```

the file gets saved with the right type and the number of pages is correct, but it's totally blank. 
Opening it with an editor, it turned out the it contains only the first part of the data returned by the server, like it's truncated.

Thank everyone for helping out!

Comment: Did you solved this?

Comment: Same question here.. ;-) Did you find a solution? Thanks.

Comment: Check this out:  
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33100281/angularjs-filesaver-producing-empty-file

Answer (score 8):

$http.get probably isn't handling binary data correctly. Try `$http({method: "GET", url: URL, responseType: "arraybuffer", ...})` [(see angularjs)](https://github.com/jesselpalmer/angular.js/commit/ba32d364051b6252f20108dd4052f20a76bc8533) to get a binary object you can put in for data.

You can also use `responseType: "blob"` so you don't even have to create `var blob`, but I think that responseType has less browser support.

Comment: Thank you, this is a lifesaver. Had a request that was working perfectly last week, and just stopped working today. This resurrected the download.

Answer (score 0):

Adding a response type to the config argument worked for me.  Try:

```
var config = { responseType: 'blob', headers: {"Authorization":"Bearer "+token, 
"Accept":"application/pdf"}};

  $http.get(URL, config)
      .success(function (data) {
          var blob = new Blob([data], {type: 'application/pdf'});
          saveAs(blob, 'contract.pdf');
       });
```