# Download PDF using AngularJS

Tags: ruby-on-rails, angularjs, filesaver.js

I need to download a file using `AngularJS`. I have a `Ruby on Rails` applications.

When the user click in a `PDF` link, i send a request to the server where he makes another request to a `JasperReports Server` returning a `PDF`.

Everything is working, except that i can't read the file, its returning only a `[object Object]`.

The server return this:

[image]

and this is what i'm doing to read this file:

```
$http.get('/my/api/path/' + object.id + '/pdf').then(function (data) {

        var hiddenElement = document.createElement('a');
        hiddenElement.href = 'data:attachment/pdf,' + encodeURI(data.data);
        hiddenElement.target = '_blank';
        hiddenElement.download = 'test.pdf';
        hiddenElement.click();

    }, function () {

    });
```

What i'm missing?

PS.: Without `AngularJS` flawless.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to follow the solution from [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26764880/2767026). `$http.get` is not handling binary data correctly.

Answer (score 3):

I believe when using `Resource` any returned data, no matter the type defined, is converted into an object in some way. Log the `data` and I think you'l find an object where each key is an int `(0 .. n)` and each value is a single character. So if the response returned `Hello World` your response would look like `{0: 'H', 1: 'e', 2: 'l', 3: 'l', 4: ' ', 5: 'W', 6: 'o', 7: 'r', 8: 'l', 9: 'd'}`.

Try using `$http` instead. This won't process the response in any special manor.

Comment: Already tried and did not work. Keep returning `[object Object]`.

Comment: Which part is returning `[object Object]`? The $http response?

Comment: I fixed the `[Object object]` problem, but now my pages are all blank. The pdf number of pages is correct, but it have nothing printed. Will update my question with my modifications.

Comment: You should continue to use FileSaver

Comment: No matter with or without filesaver, the problem is the same. =(