# AngularJS FileSaver producing empty file

Tags: php, angularjs, docx, filesaver.js

I have the following PHP code which outputs a document from a web service:

```
    $db->where('documentReference', $post->documentID);
    $results = $db->getOne('documents');
    $filelocation = 'doc/';
    $file = $results['filename'];
    header('Content-type: application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document');
    header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($filelocation.$file)); 
    header('Content-disposition: attachment; filename="'.$file.'"');
    readfile($filelocation.$file);
```

And on the front end..

```
    APIService.registerUser($scope.formData).then(function(data){
    var blob = new Blob([data.data], {type: 'application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document'});
    var config = {
        data: blob,
        filename: 'test.docx'
    };
      FileSaver.saveAs(config);
    });
}
```

When I inspect the data returned from the API the document get returned fine, but when being saved it's always empty?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When calling the API endpoint you need to set the responseType to array buffer like so:

```
    var promise = $http.post('http://someurl', formData, {responseType: 'arraybuffer'});
    return promise;
```

The file then gets saved properly.

Comment: Also on this if you're returning from PHP make sure you don't have a newline after your closing ?>